# Last menu item in CSS menu falling to next line

Tags: html, css, menu

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question.
I am working on the following site:

http://lighting-originals.myshopify.com/pages/contact-us/

As you can see, there is a menu on the top of the page made up of some items with drop downs, some without.
For some reason, the last menu item falls to the next line. It does not seem to make a difference which item I put last or whether or not it has a drop down.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: isnt it just the width of the total menu? Could you make something in jsfiddle or show us the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

style.css line no. 266 update it

```
#top-menu li.last a {
border: none;
border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
position: relative;
right: 295px;
top: 34px;
}
```

updated code

```
#top-menu li.last a {
    border: none;    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove relative position on the following style:-

```
#top-menu li.last a {
border: none;
border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
position: relative;  //Remove this
right: 295px;
top: 34px;
}
```

Your last `li` and its `div` are in the appropriate place but positioning of `a` inside the div wraps it down. It should work with just the removal of position from the above style.

This causes the followng Div to wrap down.

```
<div class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="/pages/brands" class="clearfix">
                <span class="nav-label">Shop By Brand</span>
                <span class="nav-arrow" style="top: 16px;"></span>
              </a>
              <ul style="top: 37px; display: none;">

                <li><a href="/collections/elk">Elk</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! The other guy answered a minute before, so I marked his as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem you marked it for the right one itself... Thanks for the vote though... :)